# Swagger 3 and Java >= 9 Jigsaw

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, java-11, java-9, springfox

I'm having trouble by configuring Swagger 3 on my maven-based Java11 application.

First I have declared in the `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then, I configure Swagger using Spring Beans:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPlugin() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.***.***.controller.rest"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(metaData());
}

private ApiInfo metaData() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("***")
            .description("***")
            .contact(new Contact("**", "www.***.com", "**"))
            .license("Apache 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .build();
}
```

}

And finally, I have declared the `module-info.java` requires:

```
    requires springfox.swagger2;
    requires springfox.spring.web;
    requires springfox.core;
```

When I try to `mvn clean install`, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: the *** module reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.core and springfox.spi
[ERROR] error: module springfox.spring.web reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module springfox.swagger2 reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module java.annotation reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module spring.core reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module java.validation reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module spring.beans reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module spring.web reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module spring.context reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module swagger.annotations reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module spring.boot reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module springfox.core reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] error: module springfox.spi reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.core and springfox.spi
[ERROR] error: module spring.boot.autoconfigure reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.spi and springfox.core
[ERROR] /private/tmp/***/src/main/java/module-info.java:[1] error: module *** reads package springfox.documentation.service from both springfox.core and springfox.spi
[INFO] 15 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

I guess made a mistake but I can't find it. Could anyone help me?

Comment: look for questions here with
 **module A reads package B from both X and Y**

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, there is no official solution to solve this issue with.
however by using maven-shade-plugin and merging the two springfox.core and springfox.spi jar in one package is the best workaround to run your project.

Add this dependency mentioned this URL: https://jitpack.io/#valery1707/springfox-assembly

```
requires springfox.assembly;
```

instead of

```
 requires springfox.core;
 requires springfox.spi
```